# Update the APK file on play store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to update the APK file on Google play store.

[image]

After uploading new APK file, i clicked Activate, It asked whether to replace the previous APK  file, i clicked ok. Then i get this:

[image]

But when i refresh the page i again get the 1st Image. Moreover if i search for my Application, and click on it, It shows Version as 1.0, not 1.0.1.

Is it because, Google takes time to process this? If thats the case, it atleast shouldn't show the 2 APK files, which looks like i didn't Activate it.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes some time to actually get to play market. Couple hours maybe.

You can see your old APK in advanced mode.

Comment: In advanced mode, the New APK file has **Deactivate** and Old APK file has **ReActivate**. Which mean it worked right?

Answer (score 0):

After Activate new uploaded apk save the changes you have done. may this help you